# Sending ihex file over UDP using sockets

Tags: wireless-networking, udp, sockets, multicast

I am working with **IPv6 and UDP sockets** using **python-2.7**. I am particularly focusing on **IPv6 Multicasting** `ff02::1` where every Link-Local address device (with `fe80::`) responds to queries from a central server entity.

I have Microcontrollers attached to these devices which need a program in the form of `.ihex` (**Intel Hex**). A snippet of the file is as below:

```
:103100005542200135D0085A8245381131400031EE
:103110003F4002000F9308249242381120012F8370
:103120009F4F1E390011F8233F4036000F930724AC
```

I thing the way to go about it is using `struct` and using functions like `pack` and `unpack` but I am not sure whether sending such an **ihex** file which is in the size of few **Kbs** would solve the purpose.

Can I do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from struct import pack, unpack
import socket
.   # Create a UDP socket and Bind it..
.
myHexCode = open("Filename.ihex")
dataToSend = struct.pack('Paramaters for packing', myHexCode)
.
. Send data to socket..
```

What will be the Packing Parameters ? (should I do `!` or Big or small Endian `>` or `<` for the Hex File?)

#### Note

I cannot use `scp` nor `sftp` since both these protocols work on **TCP** and do not support Multicasting and I am working in an environment where Losses in the Network may be higher (*Wireless Medium*)

Comment: If you expect high packet loss, how on earth would UDP be _better_?

Comment: hi I know but this is just experimental. I am working on Code Dissemination in wireless Networks and TCP isn't a wise choice either.